# Finding second degree intersection from intersection matrix

Tags: c++, algorithm, clique

I have n rectangles and I need to find how many of them overlap. Which I have done and created an intersection matrix which looks like this [image: Intersection Matrix] for the below JSON where each entry presents a rectangle and 1 represents there is an overlap. It is a symmetric matrix and i have assumed that a rectangle overlaps itself.

```
{
 "rects": [
          {"x": 100, "y": 100, "w": 250, "h": 80 },
          {"x": 120, "y": 200, "w": 250, "h": 150 },
          {"x": 140, "y": 160, "w": 250, "h": 100 },
          {"x": 160, "y": 140, "w": 350, "h": 190 }
          ]
 }
```

Now I know that there can be 2 or more rectangles overlapping each other. How can I find them using this intersection matrix? Or is there any other approach for this?

e.g 1,3,4 and 2,3,4

Comment: If rectangle *a* overlaps with *b*, and *b* overlaps with *c*, and *a* overlaps with *c*, then due to the geometry of a rectangle, we know that *a*, *b* and *c* have a common "subspace".

Comment: Unclear what you want. Do you want to find all triplets overlapping, all groups (with more than 2 rectangles) overlapping, biggest group, size of biggest group ?

Comment: all groups with more than 2 rectangles

Comment: If you interpret your matrix as an adjacency matrix of a graph, you are trying to find [cliques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem) of this graph. Check the linked Wikipedia article for some algorithms.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That's good for finding the triplets but whats with the quads?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem What do you mean by "common subspace"?

Comment: @DevMac: the fact that is one (or more) 2d coordinates that are elements of the three rectangles.